Single Browser Window for an application when opened from multiple consuming applications
Let's say there is an application AppOne and multiple consumers ClientOne, ClientTwo, ClientThree and so on are opening this application.
Client applications opens application AppOne with a same named window with window name "application-one".
Ex: window.open("","application-one").

Problem:

A separate browser window opens for each client. If ClientOne, ClientTwo and ClientThree opens AppOne, there will be three browser windows open with the same window name.
Have directed client applications to open AppOne with same window name as discussed above.
It always opens up a new browser window as the domain of the client applications differs.
However on multiple invocation of AppOne application by ClientOne opens only one browser window.
It either refreshes a opened window if it's already open or opens a new window if it doesn't exist.

Expectation:

I would like to see only one browser window open all the time as long as the window name is "application-one".
How Can I achieve this behaviour in AppOne ?
I'm looking for a solution that can be implemented at AppOne rather than imposing a probable solution on the client applications.
I would really appreciate for any leads on this issue !
Edit:
Typically, user UserOne would be using ClientOne, ClientTwo and ClientThree applications from a same machine and browser to invoke AppOne
Please find the below examples which simulates the problem.
ClientOne App:     https://jsfiddle.net/siddhutm/spa612tx/4/
ClientTwo App:     https://jsfiddle.net/siddhutm/x39y8a0v/2/
AppOne App:        https://jsfiddle.net/siddhutm/dvhm321t/


On click of button "Click to Open AppOne" from apps ClientOne and ClientTwo would open AppOne.
User UserOne would be working on both apps as mentioned above from the same browser.

"If ClientOne, ClientTwo and ClientThree opens ..." Are all three clients using the same machine to open the app? Wouldn't each client have their own machine and browser?

Let's say user UseOne would typically be using ClientOne, ClientTwo and ClientThree applications from the same machine and browser to invoke AppOne.

Technically, what is "AppOne"? What is "ClientOne"? Where and how does each of them run?

Please [edit] your question to include a [mre] so that we can see this in context.

@StefanHegny: I've updated my question with examples which simulates the problem.
Kindly check and let me know.

So they will always be coming from separate browser windows/tabs? I'm not sure if window.open() is supposed to work like that.  I think the window.open() calls would have to come from the same browser window/tab to use the same new window.

In the same browser, UserOne would work on ClientOne App for some time and then switch to ClientTwo in a new tab.
You can imagine, ClientOne, ClientTwo and AppOne apps being opened as tabs in the same browser.
